# How to pivot dates to columns after using groupby, ultimately trying to make a heatmap (using pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I used `df.groupby` to create a smaller dataset `(df_region_decade)`, which I'd like to be more square-shaped. In order to do this, I'd like to move 'year_cat' to the columns, with `'eventid'.count()` being the values.

Ultimately, I'd like to create a `seaborn` heatmap with regions on the y-axis and years on the x-axis.

[image: Grouped Dataframe looks like this]

When I try to pivot it, with the aforementioned "goals", I receive a:

> Key_Error: 'region_txt'

[image: The error I receive]

I also tried to reset the index and work from there, but I did not manage to fix the problem.

Comment: you need to access index with usage of multi index `df.index.get_level_values(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider avoiding indexing the grouping columns in [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `as_index=False` in order to be accessible elements in [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df_region_decade = df.groupby(['region_txt', 'year_cat'], as_index=False)['eventId'].count()

df_pivot = df_region_decade.pivot(index = 'region_text', 
                                  columns = 'year_cat',
                                  values = 'eventId')
```

Alternatively, use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) which is roughly synonymous to `groupby` + `pivot`:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index = 'region_txt',  
                          columns = 'year_cat', 
                          values = 'eventid', 
                          aggfunc = 'count')
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, very helpful! Exactly what I was looking for.